# Can i omit commas in sentence with multiple verbs connected by て-form (with "and" meaning)?

Tags: grammar, て-form

For example, I have sentence: 朝ご飯を食べて、学校に行きました。
Can I omit the comma or it is required?

Answer (score 1):

You can omit it, but reading and understanding will become much harder. Therefore, I am recommending using comma. Furthermore ~て has multiple meanings. In written Japanese 「朝ご飯を食べ、学校に行きました」would be used, because this Verb-form has only one meaning "and" and is easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! :)